# Boot sends Ubuntu into emergency mode after Win10 install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

I managed to install Windows 10 on my laptop that already ran Ubuntu by [following these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu), but I have a problem at the last step to rebuild [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html).

I used boot-repair to try and fix the problem but without success, you can find the report here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/B8d2yMn8xQ/

Still, it detects both OS. But `/dev/sda1` shows as empty, which I guess is part of the problem.

I have Boot Mode UEFI and Secure Boot OFF (don't know if it is relevant).

Now my laptop boots normally in Windows, but when I try Ubuntu it causes a dependency error in `/home` and I cannot boot.

I included a picture of the problem and tried the command `cat /etc/fstab` (see picture).
I don't know how to interpret this and any help is greatly appreciated.

I think this question may also be related but I don't know what to modify in the fstab : [Wrong fstab cause to fail boot UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048828/wrong-fstab-cause-to-fail-boot-ubuntu)
Maybe this one also [My pc is booting in to emergency mode: failed to mount /media/cdrom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960693/my-pc-is-booting-in-to-emergency-mode-failed-to-mount-media-cdrom)

[picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raIuQ.jpg)

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Boot Mode = UEFI and Secure Boot = OFF is very good. Which release number of Ubuntu are you working with?

Comment: You have LVM, is it also encrypted? If not encrypted, you can skip those steps. Use LVM tools to mount your /home VGsys-home and run fsck on it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu

Comment: I do not know if it is encrypted. How can I know it? Release number of Ubuntu is 18.04 I believe.